# What directory is GCP Cloud Shell working in?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to set up a basic Python development environment through GCP's Cloud Shell command line interface and I'm trying to activate a virtualenv to run some stuff in Dataflow. However I'm finding that I'm confused as to which directory the Cloud Shell is operating in.

My prompt shows the following:

```
my_name@cloudshell:~ (my-project-name)$
```

I installed virtualenv on my local machine in a prior session, and just now tried to activate a virtual environment through this previously installed activation file on my local machine with

```
source C:/Folder1/Folder2/virtualenv/Scripts/activate
```

but I kept getting "No such file or directory" even though this is the correct path. After some sleuthing, I found out that Cloud Shell is operating from the following directory by default:

```
/home/my_name/C:/Folder1/Folder2/virtualenv
```

(in which there's no 'Scripts' folder, which was causing the directory error)

This `/home/my_name/...` prefix directory is nowhere to be found on my local machine. I'm realizing I have no idea what directory the Cloud Shell is working from.

I have a feeling that I've installed a lot of my environment files under this weird ghost directory (possibly inadvertently) and so now I've lost control over the structure of my development environment, because now I have virtualenv files on my local machine, and some other virtualenv files in this ghost directory.

Can somebody explain

1) Where this directory is located on my machine, if it's even there at all?

2) If I'm *supposed* to setup my entire environment from within this ghost directory?

3) If I just messed up my environment installation from the start and should start over?

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: I had always assumed that Cloud Shell was a Unix environment whereas the paths you are mentioning are Windows like (C drive - C:).

In Unix you can run `pwd` to determine your current directory.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you're expecting virtual environments created locally to be available in Cloud Shell?

Comment: @Kolban yes, pwd is how I found out about this issue. I'm needing clarification about what environment is which, since the current directory doesn't seem to exist on my local machine.

Comment: @Dustin I am assuming that Cloud Shell is able to interface with my local machine, and interact with a virtual environment that is sourced on my local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud Shell (not to be confused with gcloud program) runs in a Virtual Machine in the Google Cloud. It knows nothing about your desktop. You are able to upload / download files from / to your desktop using the web browser that contains the UI for Cloud Shell.

Comment: Ok this makes sense. But I installed virtualenv (along with the activate file I need to activate the virtual environment) on my local machine during the install process, but I don’t seem to have the ability to activate from my local machine because of this Cloud Shell directory issue. Should I have installed it into this GCVM instead?

Comment: If you are doing development, you don't need Google Cloud Shell. Install gcloud, sdk, etc. on your desktop and develop locally. The Google Cloud Shell does not save anything between invocations. The Cloud Shell is a great environment, but it is not meant for development.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) on Mac or Linux with `gcloud alpha cloud-shell` to mount your local directories (as detailed in [this blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-the-ability-to-connect-to-cloud-shell-from-any-terminal)), Cloud Shell won't have access to your local filesystem.

Comment: If it doesn’t access my local filesystem, how was I able to use it to install virtualenv on my local system? Also, if this directory isn’t on my local system, where is it?

Comment: Perhaps you copied the files there? Or perhaps you already had virtualenv installed? Either way, Cloud Shell runs in a virtual machine in the cloud, so it doesn't know anything about your local system.